# Postgres EAV to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I have an entity, attribute, value table in which the definition of the attributes also exists as entities. In the example below it stores the firstname and lastname attributes of entities. The attr 33 is "known" and defines an attribute, the value is the name of the attribute. So the third row in the example has attr=1 which points to entity=1 of the first row.

```
entity | attr | value
-------+------+------
     1 |   33 | FirstName
     2 |   33 | LastName
     3 |    1 | John
     3 |    2 | Doe
     4 |    1 | Bruce
     4 |    2 | Willis
     5 |    1 | Mark
     5 |    2 | Hamill
```

I want to retrieve this table without the overhead of repeating the entity and attr ids in the result (as in the real world there are many rows and the ids are uuid). So for this reason I want to retrieve the above table in the JSON format below:

```
[
    [{'Id': 1, 'name': 'FirstName'}, {'Id': 2, 'name': 'Lastname'}],
    [3, 'John', 'Doe'],
    [4, 'Bruce','Willis'],
    [5, 'Mark', 'Hamill']
]
```

Is there any performant way of doing this in postgres 9.5?

Comment: This sounds like a fun problem I wouldn't mind working on, but I have a couple notes: First, JSON doesn't support numeric dictionary keys, so it needs to be `{"1": "FirstName"}`. Second, dictionaries are unordered, so how do you know that `John` is a `FirstName` and not a `LastName`?

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth: Very good points! I've adjusted the JSON format in the question in a way I think solves both your points. Thanks for having a look at it!